# JavaFX label not updating

Tags: javafx

I have a label (called display) set up in javaFX, and I am trying to fill it with a char[]. For some reason, the display.setText() method is updating the contents, but not displaying in the window (it still has the filler text "label"). If anyone could help, that would be great. Here is my code:

```
public void display()
{
    System.out.println("display");
    String toPrint="";
    for(int r=0;r<grid.length;r++)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<grid.length;c++)
            toPrint+=grid[r][c];
        toPrint+="\n";
    }
    System.out.println("");
    display.setText(toPrint);
    System.out.println(display.getText());
}
```

Comment: Please provide more code so that we can help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the last line of your code prints out the expected result. The reason for your problem is probably outside the code you have shown here. There may also be a misunderstanding on your side. Calling display.setText does not immediately render the new text. This will be done with the next pulse. So if there is something else in your code which prevents the next pulse (blocks the UI-thread) then the new text will never be shown. This is of course just a guess because you do not provide enough code to confirm this guess.